# nginx "try_files" directive is not allowed here

Tags: nginx, vhosts

What I want to achieve is pretty simple :

**If the subdomain starts with `admin`, try to serve directly from controller `admin.php` for all other cases, try to serve files with `site.php`.**

Note that I don't know domain names as a lot of domains are pointing to us.
What I tried so far:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    root /path/to/current/web;

    location / {
        if ($http_host ~ "^admin") {
            try_files $uri @rewriteadmin;
        }
        if ($http_host !~ "^admin") {
            try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
        }
    } 

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /site.php/$1 last;
    }

    location @rewriteadmin {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /admin.php/$1 last;
    }
    ...
 }
```

Of course this setup doesn't work and gives me : `[emerg] "try_files" directive is not allowed here`.

What's the best practice to achieve that please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regexps in `server_name`. So it's better to use two server blocks.

```
server {
    listen 8080 default_server;
    root /path/to/current/web;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    } 

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /site.php/$1 last;
    }

    ...
}

server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name ~^admin;
    # or better, if they all starts with "admin." token
    # server_name admin.*;
    root /path/to/current/web;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @rewriteadmin;
    } 

    location @rewriteadmin {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /admin.php/$1 last;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Quite, yes. Otherwise nginx could choose admin server to be default (it should not, but anything happens). It's OK, if you set up some other server as default, just make sure it's not one which process admin requests.

Comment: Yes, sorry I removed my question before you answered because i found the explication on the web. To keep a trace for others, i was asking the importance of `default_server`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: `try_files` needs to be inside a `location`.

Quick fix:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Works for my CakePHP v 3.x